# Trigger defined ComboBox<T> EventHandler<ActionEvent> programatically

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Consider this:

```
ComboBox<T>.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
        // Do something.
    }
}

//...

public void triggerDefinedComboBoxEventHandler() {
    // "Click/fire/trigger" ComboBox<T>, in order to perform
    // action described in it's "setOnAction()" body.
}
```

What is the best approach, to achieve functionality described above? Unfortunately, I can't find anything for the `javafx.scene.control.ComboBox<T>` component, which is the same, or at least similar to the `javafx.scene.control.Button.fire()` method. Therefore, so far I was using the solution as showed below:

```
public void doSomething() {
    // Do something.
}

//...

ComboBox<T>.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
        doSomething();
    }
}

//...

public void triggerDefinedComboBoxEventHandler() {
    doSomething();
}
```

...but it seems to be inelegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Event.fireEvent(comboBox, new ActionEvent());`